# How do I copy only the required rows from one csv file to other csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a program that copies rows of one.csv file to five.csv only if there is atleast one of the following('Urology','Urologist','Urologists','MD','D.name') in second column of one.csv file.

for example:
one.csv file looks like this(below).

```
date        D.name      location        speciality      comment
12th may    sth MD          MS          urologist       very good 
12th June   sth             MS          urologist       very good
```

now after running my code I should get five.csv file with following contents(below).

```
date        D.name      location        speciality      comment
12th may    sth MD          MS          urologist       very good
```

only the row that has at least one of the following ('Urology','Urologist','Urologists', 'MD','Doctor Name') is supposed to be copied to five.csv.

But, I am getting this instead

```
12th may    urologist           MS          urologist       very good 
12th June   urologist           MS          urologist       very good
```

There is no heading row and the 'speciality' seems to have doubled by replacing D.name column in the new file. I have been trying to fix this since yesterday but no solution at all.

How do I fix this ?

This is my code :

```
import csv
input = open('test.csv', 'rb')
output = open('first_test.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    for row[1] in row:
        if (('Urology' in row[1]) or ('Urologist' in row[1]) or ('Urologists' in row[1]) or ('MD' in row[1]) or ('D.name' in row[1])):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the inner loop.

```
for row[1] in row:
    ...
```

This bit is unnecessary here, you'll end up iterating over each character in `row[1]` and perform the same operation multiple times.

While refactoring your code, I recommend using the `with` statement to handle your files:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as input, open('first_test.csv', 'wb') as output: 
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        if (('Urology' in row[1]) or ('Urologist' in row[1]) or ('Urologists' in row[1]) or ('MD' in row[1]) or ('D.name' in row[1])):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

You don't have to worry about closing your files now.

Answer (score 0):

Another cleaner way would be have all the to-be-searched string saved in a tuple and use any operator to search all strings. This will avoid adding an additional condition in if condition instead you just need to add new string in expected tuple.

```
import platform
import csv

def readWrite():
  ## List all the to-be-searched strings
  expected = ('Urology', 'Urologist', 'Urologists', 'MD', 'D.name')
  with open('test.csv', 'r') as input, open('first_test.csv', 'w') as output: 
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in csv.reader(input):
      ## search all strings in above listed list
      if any(string in row[1] for string in expected):
        writer.writerow(row)
  with open('first_test.csv', 'r') as f:
    print (f.read())


print("Python version : " + platform.python_version())
readWrite()
```

Sample Run

```
Python version : 3.6.1
date,D.name,location,speciality,comment

12th may,sth MD,MS,urologist,very good
```